# Primary Interop Assemblies (PIA) for Office 2007 - 32/64bit?

Tags: .net, ms-office, office-interop, office-pia

Are the Primary Interop Assemblies (PIA) for Office 2007 compatible with both 32 bit and 64 bit versions of Windows?

Are they compiled with a target of any processor?

Also, is there a way I can verify this, say by using a tool like Reflector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Office 2007 is a 32 bit application so you can only use interop from another 32-bit application.

This applies to both 32 and 64-bit operating systems.

Mark your application as x86 in Visual Studio (not "Any CPU").

Comment: This works until you get into an environment where the user has multiple versions of Office installed. For example, they install Office 2010 x64 and use MS Project 2007 (32-bit). We were getting exceptions in this scenario and the only way around it was through late binding.